# how to get info about an rq worker working on a remote redis

Tags: python-rq

I'm trying to run the `rq info` command, but I want to get info on a remote redis machine. how do I specify the url of the redis machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

turns out this is simple but undocumented:

```
rq info --url redis://my-server-stage.blah.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 -R
```

That '-R' there tells the command to list info about all existing queues.